# PHP preg_replace URL pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

I have the following URL structure:

```
http://website.com/images/folder1/folder2/123456/x500x1000_2x_ImageName.jpg
```

I need to remove the crop resolution "x500x1000_2x_" from the image name, like so:

```
http://website.com/uploads/folder1/folder2/123456/ImageName.jpg
```

I tried numerous things:

```
$img = preg_replace('/\[x](\d+)[x](\d+)[_2x_]\.*/', '', $img);
$img = preg_replace('/[x]\d[x]\d[_2x_]\.*/', '', $img);
$img = preg_replace('/\/\[x]+\d+[x]+\d+\D+\d\.*/', '', $img);
```

I am really not good with preg_replace, can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I just replace `x\d+x\d+_\d+x_` of the [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) of the url with [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). At the end I just concatenate the url again with [`dirname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) together)

```
<?php

    $img = "http://website.com/images/folder1/folder2/123456/x500x1000_2x_ImageName.jpg";
    echo $img = dirname($img) . "/" . preg_replace("/x\d+x\d+_\d+x_/", "", basename($img));

?>
```

output:

```
http://website.com/images/folder1/folder2/123456/ImageName.jpg
```

regex explanation:

```
x\d+x\d+_\d+x_
```

- **x** matches the character x literally (case sensitive)
- **\d+** match a digit [0-9]

  - Quantifier: **+** Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
- **x** matches the character x literally (case sensitive)
- **\d+** match a digit [0-9]

  - Quantifier: **+** Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
- **_** matches the character _ literally
- **\d+** match a digit [0-9]

  - Quantifier: **+** Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
- **x_** matches the characters x_ literally (case sensitive)

Comment: I was about to write that it's going to cause a problem if the name contains underscore but you have already changed it. :-) +1

Comment: thanks for that! works great! (someone else must have edited it actually, wasn't me) :-)